# The Galois representation of a p-divisible group is crystalline

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, crystalline-cohomology, p-adic-analysis

Can someone explain (or give a reference) why the Galois representation attached to a p-divisible group over the ring of integers of a p-adic ring is Crystalline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is shown in §6 of Fontaine's paper "Sur certains types de représentations p-adiques du groupe de Galois d'un corps local; construction d'un anneau de Barsotti-Tate", see the point i) after Theorem 6.2.

The paper is available on jstor: http://www.jstor.org/pss/2007012